# vim always shows help/documentation

Tags: centos, vim

Whenever I run vim, it randomly shows the help/documentation at a non particular time. How do I disable that. It's irritating.

Comment: This isn't normal behavior. Does it only happen with certain kinds of files? Anything else you can tell us about the circumstances?

Comment: It happens everytime, on every file. Especially when I am idle, I did a clean install of vim on my CentOS. I am opening it on putty by the way.

Comment: I know now what's happening the help document always shows on split screen. How can I stop that behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use default Vim settings:

```
vim -u NONE -U NONE
```

also try disable all plugins:

```
vim --noplugin
```